# Any idea how to linearize this equation? $X^2-Y^2=aZ+bZ^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus

The intention is to linearize this equation $X^2-Y^2=aZ+bZ^2$ into something which looks like $Z=mX+nY+c$ so that a graph of $Z$ against $X$ or $Y$ can be plotted.

X,Y,Z are variables while a,b,c are constants

Comment: Well, $4b(X^2-Y^2)=(2bZ+a)^2-a^2$, so there's that. Up to an affine transformation this is a cone, but I don't think $Z=mX^2+nY^2+c$ can be a cone...

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use implicit function theorem for 3 variables. Use it to find $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} $ and $\frac {\partial z}{\partial y} $.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what to do next after finding $∂z/∂x$ and $∂z/∂y$?

Comment: Well $m$ is $\frac {\partial z}{\partial x} $ and $n$ is $\frac {\partial z}{\partial y} $. And to linearize something you need a point associated with the solid. You have to linearize about a point on the function or in this case relation (solid). So you have to evaluate $ m$ and $ n $, the two partials I just spoke about, at a point on the solid. Let's call that point $(x_1, y_1, z_1) $ . Then do $ z-z_1=m (x-x_1) +n (y-y _1) $ and simplify. Do you know how to find a point on the solid ? It might be messy since you don't know what $ A $ and $ B $ are.

Comment: No that is why I do not know how to proceed right now. What about trying to achieve $Z=mX^2 + nY^2$?

Comment: That's not a linearization nor a 2nd degree taylor for it. That equation does not act as a linearization. Even if you do a 2nd degree taylor for it your still stuck with finding the point, and have to deal with 3 ugly 2nd partial derivs. Stick with the first degree. Definetly try to complete the square for $ z $. You don't need to complete the square to find the partial corresponding to $ m $ and $ n $, just to find the point on the solid.  After you complete the square plug in like $ x $ =0 , $ y $=0 and get $ z$ . Try that.

Comment: Unless you are talking about something else when you say linearization, like what Jim Smith did. What I am telling you to do is planar approximation a.k.a linearization.

Comment: I am trying to simplify $X^2−Y^2=aZ+bZ^2$ into $Z=mX+nY+c$ so that I can plot a graph of Z against X or Y to give me an approximation of m,n and c.

Comment: Oh, I think we were on the wrong page. Ok so Jim Smith's method allows you to plot $ W $ vs $ X^2$ and $ Y^2$. There is no way to plot $ Z$ in terms of $ X^2$ and $ Y^2$ because of the two terms on the right $ Z $ has. If there was just a first power $ Z $ on the right you also cannot write $ Z $ in terms of $ X $ and $ Y $  linearly unless you use a linear approximation like I was saying which requires a known point on the solid and gets worse as you choose values for x and y further away from the chosen point.

Comment: I think you originally wanted Jim Smith's method, but you must use $ W $ and $ X^2,Y^2$. If $ z $ was only to the first power you could have done $ Z $ in terms of $ x^2, y^2$

Comment: Yes. Having $Z$ in quadratic messes up everything. Thanks anyway dylan, you have helped me a lot. 

If there is any chance of an eureka, just let me know 

Thanks again, Dylan :D

Comment: No problem, glad to help. Unfortunately, the word linearization is used for multiple things. Jim Smith's method preserves your equation completely but changes coordinate systems from x, y, z to u, v, w. Mine stays in x, y, z but only gives an ok approximation of the equation, known as linear approximation.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** *Thanks to dylan37 for pointing out that the this is probably not the sort of "linearization" that curiousfurious (the OP) intended.*

Maybe you could use the trick that's employed in deriving the Quadratic Formula.

Starting from $ X^{2}-Y^{2}=aZ+bZ^{2}$, first divide both sides by $b$ to get

$\frac{1}{b}X^{2}-\frac{1}{b}Y^{2}=\frac{a}{b}Z+Z^{2}=2\left(\frac{a}{2b}\right)Z+Z^{2}.$

Now, complete the square:

$
\frac{1}{b}X^{2}-\frac{1}{b}Y^{2}+\frac{a^{2}}{4b^{2}}=\frac{a^{2}}{4b^{2}}+2\left(\frac{a}{2b}\right)Z+Z^{2}=(Z+\frac{a}{2b})^{2}
$

Finally, let$\;\;U=X^{2};\;\;V=Y^{2};\;\;W=(Z+\frac{a}{2b})^{2}.$

In this way,

$X^{2}-Y^{2}=aZ+bZ^{2}$ becomes $\frac{1}{b}U-\frac{1}{b}V+\frac{a^{2}}{4b^{2}}=W$, or $W=\frac{1}{b}U-\frac{1}{b}V+\frac{a^{2}}{4b^{2}}$.

Comment: I didn't think that is what curiousfurious meant by linearization. I thought the question had to do with planar approximation also known as linearization.

Comment: Well, this looks interesting. I am actually trying to simplify the equation into $Z=mX+nY+c$ form so that I can plot a graph of Z against X or Y to give me an approximation of m,n and c. Sorry if I did not make that clear. 

Thanks still, we can look for more ways to solve this